# How to fix this error i am stuck..i want to create login page

Tags: java, android

I tried to create login page using volley on the fragment tab but i got error on my java code at 
 volley.newRequesQueue(this).add(request);

I am new to android and i don't know what is this error which is dragging me behind.I want to connect it 
 to my database.

the error says "newRequestQueue(android.content.context) in Volley cannot be applied to 
 (com.example.myandroidprac.loginpage)" Below is the code: -

```
 package com.example.myandroidprac;

 import android.os.Bundle;

 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

 import android.view.LayoutInflater;

 import android.view.View;

  enter code here

 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import android.widget.Button;

 import android.widget.EditText;

 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;

 import com.android.volley.Request;

 import com.android.volley.Response;

 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;

 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

 import java.util.HashMap;

 import java.util.Map;


 /**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
```

my java code appears below

```
  */

    public class loginpage extends Fragment {

    Button btn_login;

    EditText et_username, et_password;

    public loginpage() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loginpage, container, false);

        btn_login = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        et_username = v.findViewById(R.id.et_username);

        et_password = v.findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                login();
            }
        });

        return v;

    }
    public void login(){

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 

         "http://10.183.52.242/loginapp/login.php",

                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"this is 

            response:"+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
             @Override

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("username","mwalulu");

                params.put("password","coder");

                return params;
                }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }
}
```

and the UI layout code below explains what i am having on that side

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  android:id="@+id/loginPage"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"

  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  tools:context=".loginpage"

  android:paddingRight="10dp"

  android:paddingLeft="10dp">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:text="@string/logex"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_username"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="Enter Username"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/user"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="Enter Password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/pass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_username"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.065" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/logbtn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_password"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.125" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your class `extends Fragment` you cannot pass `this` as an argument to `Volley.newRequestQueue()` function. Change `this` to `getContext()`:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);
```

From Android [documentation of Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) if you take a look at direct and indirect subclasses you won't find `Fragment`. But you will find `Activity` class and many others. Thus, you can use `getActivity()` or better `getContext()` to get reference to `Context`.

So, both solutions are valid:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);
Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(request);
```

Comment: @saidhamisi, you are welcome. Accept and upvote the answer if it is correct to make it helpful to the others.